# React-Native: How to convert an animation from reanimated 2 to moti library?

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated-v2, moti

I am using [react-native-reanimated](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/) in my react-native app. But I would like to transition my animations to [moti](https://moti.fyi/).

I have a text I am animating based on the scroll position of my flatlist. By using the **useAnimatedStyle** hook, I can interpolate the **scroll position input**:

```js
const animatedFontSize = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
  fontSize: interpolate(scrollPosition.value, [0, maximumScrollHeight], [18, 12], {
    extrapolateRight: Extrapolation.CLAMP
  })
}))

return (
  <Animated.Text style={[animatedFontSize]}>
    {my text}
  </Animated.Text>
)
```

Can anyone help me to convert this dynamic animation to Moti? Most of the examples on the Moti site show rather "static" animations occurring once (e.g on mount/unmount). There is also the hook **useDynamicAnimation**. But how can I use it with an animation driven by a **shared value**?

Comment: So do you want to loop animation?

Comment: No,  I just want to animate the fontSize (from a max value to a min) and clamp the output value, as the user is scrolling through the list (up and down). There are plenty of examples with reanimated. I just could not find 1 with Moti

Answer (score 0):

[If you're on Moti 0.18+](https://github.com/nandorojo/moti/releases/tag/v0.18.0), **you can also pass a derived value directly to the `animate` prop** and it will react to shared values:

```
const animatedFontSize = useDerivedValue(() => ({
  fontSize: scrollPosition.value
}))

return (
  <MotiText animate={animate}>
    {my text}
  </MotiText>
)
```

This approach will automatically animate the value based on your `transition` prop. If you don't want this automatic animation, you can use the behavior below.

For what it's worth, anything that works on a Reanimated view works on a Moti view as well. Notice that this code is the same as yours, but with a `MotiText` instead of `Animated.Text`:

```
const animatedFontSize = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
  fontSize: scrollPosition.value
}))

return (
  <MotiText style={animatedFontSize}>
    {my text}
  </MotiText>
)
```